# python natsort: How to sort alphabetically first with an associated version number within a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, natsort

Let's say I have this list:

```
my_list = [
{'id': 'Bear@1.0.1'}, {'id': 'Bear@5.5.1'}, {'id': 'Bear@10.0.9'}, {'id': 'Bear@5.1'}, 
{'id': 'Air@7.6'}, {'id': 'Air@8.7'}, {'id': 'Air@10.0.0'}, {'id': 'Air@1.0'}
]
```

I want the resulting list to be sorted first by what precedes the @ and then by the version numbers.

Doing this: `natsort.natsorted(my_list, key=itemgetter(*['id']), reverse=True)`

I get the following result:

```
[{'id': 'Bear@10.0.9'},
 {'id': 'Bear@5.5.1'},
 {'id': 'Bear@5.1'},
 {'id': 'Bear@1.0.1'},
 {'id': 'Air@10.0.0'},
 {'id': 'Air@8.7'},
 {'id': 'Air@7.6'},
 {'id': 'Air@1.0'}]
```

How do I get natsort to work so that all the items for "Air" come before all the items for "Bear", while still sorting also by version (as it's currently doing correctly)?

Comment: So you want to sort ascending by name, but descending by version?

Comment: You told it to use `reverse=True`, so of course it put all the Bears first, because B comes after A in the alphabet.

Comment: So you want to sort everything on the _left_ side of the `@` sign in ascending order, and everything on the _right_ side in descending order?

Comment: You can only pass one value for `reverse`, so I'm not sure `natsorted()` can do that.

Comment: You might have to separate these into two lists, one for Bears and one for Airs, sort each list in reverse order, then join the lists back together.

Comment: Good questions and I do need to provide a clarification.

Yes, ascending left of the @ sign and descending to the right.

I am also wondering if this is feasibly done without a double sort.

Comment: Do you have something against a double sort? That was btw also [suggested](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/46104#issuecomment-1093405517)  in the issue that removed the cmp-parameter.

Comment: I'm still wondering. If it is because you think it's slower: two simple sorts can be faster than one complex sort, and in my experience usually *are*. Especially with one as very complex as chepner's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a custom comparison function to reverse the comparison only on the version numbers, using `natsort.natsort_keygen` to make a function that will compare versions numbers correctly.

```
from operator import methodcaller, itemgetter

my_list = [
{'id': 'Bear@1.0.1'}, {'id': 'Bear@5.5.1'}, {'id': 'Bear@10.0.9'}, {'id': 'Bear@5.1'},
{'id': 'Air@7.6'}, {'id': 'Air@8.7'}, {'id': 'Air@10.0.0'}, {'id': 'Air@1.0'}
]


vkey = natsort.natsort_keygen()

# Python 2's three-way comparison function:
#  x < y returns negative
#  x == y returns zero
#  x > y returns positive
#
# To reverse the comparison, swap the arguments.
def cmp(x, y):
    return -1 if x < y else 0 if x == y else 1



def cmp_str(x, y):
    splitter = operator.methodcaller('split', '@')
    getter = operator.itemgetter('id')
    x1, x2 = splitter(getter(x))
    y1, y2 = splitter(getter(y))
    return cmp(x1, y1) \
           or cmp(vkey(y2), vkey(x2))

for x in sorted(my_list, key=functools.cmp_to_key(cmp_str)):
    print(x)
```

Output:

```
{'id': 'Air@10.0.0'}
{'id': 'Air@8.7'}
{'id': 'Air@7.6'}
{'id': 'Air@1.0'}
{'id': 'Bear@10.0.9'}
{'id': 'Bear@5.5.1'}
{'id': 'Bear@5.1'}
{'id': 'Bear@1.0.1'}
```

Comment: What does `vkey(y2)` return?

Comment: Tuple are sorted lexicographically, so `vkey` basically just splits a version string into a tuple of the individual fields in order to sort them. Numbers are converted to `int`s, and missing fields are retained as `''`.

Comment: Ok. I was hoping it's something that supports negation, so that you could do something like `key=lambda x: (x1, -vkey(x2))`.

Comment: I wish Python 3 hadn't gotten rid of the built-in `cmp` function or the `cmp` argument to `sorted`. `sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: x.split('@'), cmp=lambda x, y: cmp(x[0], y[0]) or cmp(y[1], x[1]))` would be a fairly clean way to implement this.

Comment: Ooh, a combination of both. Interesting idea. I wonder whether that was considered. I don't think I've ever seen that.

Comment: That's how Python 2 use to work. The API was simplified in favor of only relying on the underlying comparison operators of the key value.

Comment: Yeah I just wondered what Python 2 did when you used both. It's been so long ago, I don't remember whether I've ever used or seen a combination of both. I think not.

Comment: I've just read the [issue](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/46104) about the cmp-parameter removal. Looks like they were convinced there's always a better solution with a key.

Comment: @chepner I tried your solution but the part preceding the @ sign is still not sorted. I should mention that I'm using Python 3.10.

Comment: @chepner Actually, that does work! Thank you, very much! I just needed to fix the y1, y2 = splitter(getter(x)) line so that it was splitting y, not x.

Comment: @ADiehl Sorry, that was a copy-paste error from the gratuitous introduction of `splitter` and `getter`. (The original answer was correctly splitting `y['id']`.)

Answer (score 0):

Take the natsorted list and sort it solely based on what precedes the @. The sorting is stable, so the sorting of versions is preserved.

```py
ds = [{'id': 'Bear@10.0.9'},
 {'id': 'Bear@5.5.1'},
 {'id': 'Bear@5.1'},
 {'id': 'Bear@1.0.1'},
 {'id': 'Air@10.0.0'},
 {'id': 'Air@8.7'},
 {'id': 'Air@7.6'},
 {'id': 'Air@1.0'}]

ds.sort(key=lambda d: d['id'].split('@')[0])

for d in ds:
    print(d)
```

Output ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3f6cUK9gqRFerZ6aoWymoO6UmFjkYGugZ6Fmq1-pwKaCIm-qZ6hliE8YiaAg0AlXYMRNqsgGGsIWeOYaYuZ4ZpnaQ3lgurpRiveL8ohKN7NRK25zE3KSURIUUK4WUaJDSWL3igpzMEg11B3XNaINYTS6utPwihRSFzDyFlGIrLgUgKCjKzCvRSNGEBAE0JGAhAgA)):

```
{'id': 'Air@10.0.0'}
{'id': 'Air@8.7'}
{'id': 'Air@7.6'}
{'id': 'Air@1.0'}
{'id': 'Bear@10.0.9'}
{'id': 'Bear@5.5.1'}
{'id': 'Bear@5.1'}
{'id': 'Bear@1.0.1'}
```

Comment: You may wish to tell `str.split` to only split once on `@`.

Comment: @Chris Meh. Unless they have very different data, I wouldn't bother. I did consider using `partition`, btw.

Comment: @Chris Actually I even see a reason to really *dislike* that. Because it suggests that there are entries with more than one `@`, and if that's not the case, then that's misleading. Same reason I dislike it when people write `i  >= n` instead of `i == n` when `i > n` can never happen. It's misleading, making the code harder to understand, because you're now wondering *"Wait, why do they check `>=`? Can `>` be the case? I don't think so. I'm confused."*